# How to get the size of data present in coredata store?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

How to get the total memory size in bytes of data present in core data store.And How to get the memory size for particular rows of data.

Comment: I saw this first link on search. Have you tried this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719888/how-do-i-find-the-size-of-my-core-data-persistent-store-and-the-free-space-on-th

Comment: I have checked it.I can get total memory size.Thanks.Also i need to get the memory size for particular rows in store.

Comment: Have you tried Instruments?

Answer (score 10):

On iOS 7 and above, [older answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719888/how-do-i-find-the-size-of-my-core-data-persistent-store-and-the-free-space-on-th) don't work anymore for SQLite-backed persistent stores, because of SQLite journal files. For each persistent store file you need to get the size of the SQLite file itself (e.g. `Foo.sqlite`) **and** the sizes of the journal files (e.g. `Foo.sqlite-wal` and `Foo.sqlite-shm`) and add the sizes to get the total. This is really important because it's very likely that most of the data is actually in the journal files. You can use `NSFileManager` to get this information for each file.

If you're using binary attributes in your model *and* you have "Allows External Storage" enabled for any of those attributes, it gets more complicated. In that case you need to find all of the external storage files and add up their sizes too. Their location is not documented but should be in a subdirectory of the directory where the SQLite file is found. For a SQLite file named `Foo.sqlite` look for a directory named `.Foo_SUPPORT/_EXTERNAL_DATA`, and the external binary files will be there. *Since this is not documented, it may be subject to change without warning.*

A better approach-- if it's not too late-- is to put the persistent store in its own subdirectory. Instead of putting it in the documents directory, create a new directory inside documents and put your SQLite file there. That is, create a directory called something like `data` and put `Foo.sqlite` in it. To add up the size, just recursively scan every file in `data` and add up the sizes. Then you'll catch everything, even if journaling or external binaries or whatever change in future versions of iOS. A good way to do the scan would be with `NSFileManager`'s `enumeratorAtPath:` or `enumeratorAtURL:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:errorHandler:` methods.

Finding the memory size for a particular row of data is a very different question, and there's no general solution. There's the overhead of any object instance, plus your attributes, plus any internal undocumented objects `NSManagedObject` might create (including instance vars and dynamically allocated memory). It's not even a fixed value since data can be allocated and released on the fly. Adding up the sizes of just your attributes is easy-- just run through them and add up the size of each (string length, data length, etc), but it's not the full picture.

Answer (score 5):

Using Swift 5, I came up with this answer. It not only gets the size of the store and files, but also formats the data size using Apples [ByteCountFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bytecountformatter).

```
public func getSqliteStoreSize(forPersistentContainerUrl storeUrl: URL) -> String {
    do {
        let size = try Data(contentsOf: storeUrl)
        if size.count < 1 {
            print("Size could not be determined.")
            return ""
        }
        let bcf = ByteCountFormatter()
        bcf.allowedUnits = [.useMB] // optional: restricts the units to MB only
        bcf.countStyle = .file
        let string = bcf.string(fromByteCount: Int64(size.count))
        print(string)
        return string
    } catch {
        print("Failed to get size of store: \(error)")
        return ""
    }
}
```

To use is as simple as:

```
// Get Core Data storage size:
guard let storeUrl = self.managedObjectContext!.persistentStoreCoordinator!.persistentStores.first?.url else {
    print("There is no store url")
    return
}
print("The size of the store is: \(self.getSqliteStoreSize(forPersistentContainerUrl: storeUrl))")
```

One minor detail here is to ensure you check that your `moc` and `persistentStoreCoordinator` actually have value - in my case I know that they do because of how I have initialised them.

Regarding the answer above that takes into account the `wal` and `shm` files, you can check these by appending a string to the URL:

```
let newFileName = storeUrl.absoluteString.appending("\("-wal")")
let newFileName2 = storeUrl.absoluteString.appending("\("-shm")")
print("The size of the wal is: \(self.getSqliteStoreSize(forPersistentContainerUrl: URL(string: newFileName)!))")
print("The size of the shm is: \(self.getSqliteStoreSize(forPersistentContainerUrl: URL(string: newFileName2)!))")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)reportFileSizeOfPersistentStores
{
    NSArray *allStores = self.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    for (NSPersistentStore *store in allStores)
    {
        NSString *filePath = store.URL.path;
        NSDictionary *attributes = [fileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:filePath
                                                                 error:nil];

        NSString *fileSize = attributes[NSFileSize];

        NSLog(@"FileSize:%@", fileSize);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's going to miss the SQLite journal files, which means that the result will be seriously inaccurate. Journal files frequently contain nearly all of the actual data on iOS 7 and up.